# RACSignal that indicates when a property returns to its initial value

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I have a property, `recording`, that changes to `YES` if a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is in state `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` or `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`.

How can I create an signal that will only fire when `recording` goes back to `NO` and not on its initial value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would send `@YES` every time `self.recording`'s value changes to `YES`, and ignore any `NO`s:

```
RACSignal *mySignal = [RACObserve(self, recording) ignore:@NO];
```

This would skip the initial value, regardless of whether it's `NO` or `YES`, and would send every subsequent value (either `NO` or `YES`):

```
RACSignal *mySignal = [RACObserve(self, recording) skip:1];
```

You can achieve more fine-grained control over how ReactiveCocoa KVOs your property using `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew` to only send a value if the property gets set to a new (not the initial) value:

```
RACSignal *mySignal = [self rac_valuesAndChangesForKeyPath:@"recording" 
                                                   options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                                                  observer:self];
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the [`skip:`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoaFramework/ReactiveCocoa/RACStream.h) method to skip the initial "NO" signal?